# PHP - Validate that a file only contains ASCII

Tags: php, validation, encoding, ascii

I'm writing a web application where the user upload a zip file that contains properties files and images.

I want to validate that the properties files only contains ASCII characters. Is there a way in PHP to check the whole file and return an error if a non-ASCII character is found?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the 127 chars of `US-ASCII`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

- [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://nl.php.net/mb_detect_encoding):

  ```
  mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($filename), 'ASCII', true) === false
  ```
- A regular expression:

  ```
  preg_match('/^[\x20-\x7e]*$/', file_get_contents($filename)) > 0
  ```

Comment: Thank you, had some troubles installing mbstring but it's what I was looking for.

Comment: Note: this regexp detects printable ASCII characters only.

Comment: Does this handle newlines, carriage returns, tabs?